# SQL Query, Getting multiple dates for one entity

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on writing a SQL query to produce a table that will look something like this:

```
Name    |Dates Absent|Total Absences  
student |10/28/2018  |     2       
        |10/29/2018  |
```

I currently have a data base which has 2 tables that are part of a larger system which contain the needed data (absences, students).

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT s.student_id,s.last_name,s.first_name, COUNT(s.student_id) AS 'Total Absences' 
FROM `students` s, `absences` a INNER JOIN students ON students.student_id=a.student_id
```

Which yielded the following results:

```
student_id | last_name | first_name | Total Absences
1          |   student |       name | 12464
```

I want this to only use each ID once and count the times it appears. Is the problem from a relationship in the database that has many dates the one person can be absent? The ID was left in the select for now for debugging purposes, it will be removed later.

---

**EDIT**

I now have the query

```
SELECT s.last_name, s.first_name,a.date_absence, COUNT(s.student_id) AS 'Total Absences' 
FROM `students` s, `absences` a 
INNER JOIN students ON students.student_id=a.student_id 
GROUP BY s.student_ID
```

This only displays one of the dates, how I can add all of the dates without redisplaying the students information?

Comment: a better question title would help other users in the future; the current one is too vague...

Comment: You'll need group_concat() to get the exact results you want, though often using group_concat() is a sign you're doing work on the DB you should really move the client application.

Comment: Could you explain why you changed the accepted answer? I have no problem with the accepted answer (which is now very similar to mine and I upvoted it), but that rep loss hurts!

Comment: The other answer had the wrong results, the number of days missed was in the hundreds and it should've been a single digit number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with group_concat.  It's not quite what you descibe, but it's close.

```
SELECT s.student_id,s.last_name,s.first_name, group_concat(a.date_absent) AS 'Dates Absent', COUNT(a.id) AS 'Total Absences' 
FROM `students` s JOIN `absences` a ON s.student_id = a.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_id
```

which should yield

```
student_id | last_name | first_name | Dates Absent          | Total Absences
1          |   student |       name | 10/28/2018,10/29/2018 | 2
```

Comment: looks like there's still a strange cross join going on in your solution which may affect the counts

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Students has many absences, you connect to them and group by student_id.  I don't see any potential for a cross join issue.  There could be a problem if there are multiple absences per day.

Comment: `FROM students s, absences a INNER JOIN students ...`. This will cross join the tables students and absences (creating a row for every student and absence combination), then INNER JOIN the whole lot with students again. I can't imagine this is what OP wanted.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't realize when I copied from the original query that the students table was included twice.  FIXED.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are almost there with the counting, but missing your GROUP BY statement

If you include aggregate functions, such as COUNT(), but leave off the GROUP BY, the whole intermediate result is taken as one group

You also seem to have a strange CROSS JOIN going on with your duplicate mention of the students table

If you want the absence dates in each row you'll have to use another aggregate function, GROUP_CONCAT()

Something along the lines of

```
   SELECT s.student_id, /** Include as names could feasibly be duplicated */ 
          CONCAT(s.first_name, ' ', s.last_name) name, 
          GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] a.date) dates_absent, /** May want distinct here if more than one absence is possible per diem */
          COUNT(*) total_absences 
     FROM students s
     JOIN absences a
       ON a.student_id = s.student_id
 GROUP BY s.student_id[, name] /** name required for SQL standard */
[ORDER BY name [ASC]] /** You'll probably want some kind of ordering */
```

`[]` indicate optional inclusions

Comment: @EnterStrandman, your edit appeared to be only removing the square brackets which I included only as indications of optional inclusions (after removing the square brackets). This is standard syntax in the MySQL docs. The comments are of course optional as well.